# Docker desktop macOS running Ubuntu 20 and hitting operation not permitted with bpf

Tags: ubuntu-20.04, docker-desktop, ebpf, macos-monterey

Setup details:

```
macoS 12.1, docker desktop: 4.3.2
Linux nsipsecinst-0 5.10.76-linuxkit #1 SMP Mon Nov 8 10:21:19 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Form within container

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

I am running the container with privilege and CAP_NET_ADMIN + CAP_SYS_ADMIN

```
"CapAdd": [
                "NET_ADMIN",
                "SYS_ADMIN"
            ],
            "CapDrop": null,
            "CgroupnsMode": "private",
```

Now when i try to load a simple bpf program, i get the following error in the container

```
bpf_prog_load() failed: [1] Operation not permitted
```

When i run the exact same code on a VM running kernel 5.4, it works well.
Am not sure what else is needed to make this work.
What do you suggest?
I am not able to glean anything useful from docker or linuxkit documentation that might help here.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ip-vrf.8.html you need
**CAP_SYS_ADMIN**
**CAP_NET_ADMIN**
and **CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE** capabilities.

Also you may need to mount cgroup inside to your container

Comment: I was already using NET_ADMIN and SYS_ADMIN. Appending them with DAC_OVERRIDE didnt work. Will be attempting with cgroup in container and see how it goes.

Comment: vtewari, let me know about results.